# How to filter Relations - TypeORM

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, orm, typeorm

Hello a couple of questions about TypeORM in TypeScript.

**Using only Find()**
I have 2 tables on my DB. **Users & Sessions**. *I would like to get an User and all his Sessions where the column sessions_deleted_at is NULL.*

**How am I getting an User?**

```
const user = await getRepository(Users)
    .findOne({
        select: ["user_id", "user_email", "user_password"],
        relations: ["sessions"],
        where: {
            user_email: email,
            user_deleted_at: IsNull(),
        }
    })
```

That is getting the user correctly all the sessions in `user.sessions` But I just want the sessions where session_delete_at column is NULL. I tried next but not working.

```
const user = await getRepository(Users)
    .findOne({
        select: ["user_id", "user_email", "user_password"],
        relations: ["sessions"],
        where: {
            user_email: email,
            user_deleted_at: IsNull(),
            
            sessions: {
                session_deleted_at: IsNull()
            }
        }
    })
```

I am trying to use always **find** to *pull data from the DB* and **QueryBuilders** to *Insert/Delete/Update*. I guess this is not Bad... Why use QueryBuilders if you have a Find method that 'make things easier'.

Answer (score 3):

If your table columns in DB tables have names like `id`, `email`, `deleted_at` etc. – code below should help you.

```
const user = await getRepository(Users).createQueryBuilder('user')
  .innerJoin(Sessions, 'session') 
  .select(["user.id", "user.email", "user.password", "user.deleted_at", "session.deleted_at"])
  .where('user.email = :email', { email: <user email here> })
  .addWhere({ 'user.deleted_at': IsNull() })
  .addWhere({ 'session.deleted_at': IsNull() })
  .getOne();
```

---

Else if your columns named like `user_id`, `user_email`, `user_deleted_at`, `session_deleted_at`:

```
const user = await getRepository(Users).createQueryBuilder('user')
  .innerJoin(Sessions, 'session') 
  .select(["user.user_id", "user.user_email",  "user.user_password", "user.user_deleted_at", "session.session_deleted_at"])
  .where('user.user_email = :email', { email: <user email here> })
  .addWhere({ 'user.user_deleted_at': IsNull() })
  .addWhere({ 'session.session_deleted_at': IsNull() })
  .getOne();
```

Comment: When you do innerJoin first and then add where clauses, will inner join be done first in DB query execution? I would not want to read from DB all the million rows of session, only those that match the filter.

Comment: Using only Find() was the requirement.